# What's my PPCG ID?

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

## Challenge

Given the name of a PPCG member, output their PPCG ID number. If the user does not exist, you may report an error or return any non-positive number. If there are multiple members with this name, you may choose to output only one ID or all of them.

## Test Cases

```
"musicman523" -> 69054
"Dennis" -> 12012
"xnor" -> 20260
"Leaky Nun" -> 48934
"fəˈnɛtɪk" -> 64505
"Jörg Hülsermann" -> 59107
"Community" -> -1
"Any user that does not exist" -> 0
"Alex" -> 69198 (this is one possible result)
"Leaky N" -> 0
"Jorge" -> 3716
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13196/69054)

Comment: If there are multiple users with the same name, can we output any one of them?

Comment: @Okx Yes, any of them is fine

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137085/whats-my-name)

Comment: Recommended test case: "Leaky N". Should return 0.

Comment: Can our program result in undefined behaviour for inexistent users (mine prints 48934, for example for a non-existing user)? I think this should be allowed, since errors are.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder The question states that *If the user does not exist, you may report an error or return 0*. I think you have your answer.

Comment: @Okx No, I don't. I am asking the OP if this behaviour is allowed. If it is not, I will delete or fix my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sorry, how does that not answer your question?

Comment: @Okx Sorry, can you please not be so toxic here? I see your point, but you could be a little nicer about it.

Comment: @OliverNi Toxic? How?

Comment: @Okx He is asking a valid question to the OP and you are shooting him down immediately. Let the OP answer.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You can do anything besides return a positive integer. This includes (but is not limited to) throwing an exception, returning 0, returning a negative number, etc.

Comment: @musicman I fixed my answer.

Comment: I wonder if this could be answered with a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) query...

Comment: @StevenVascellaro [Done and done.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137977)

Comment: Recommended test case: "Jorge". Should return 3716 (as of right now)

Answer (score 30):

## [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com), <s>56</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 46 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Hyper Neutrino. -5 bytes thanks to Giacomo Garabello.*

```sql
SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE##S##=DISPLAYNAME--S
```

[Try it online!](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/707635/whats-my-ppcg-id)

Not sure if this is completely valid but... Input must be surrounded in single quotes `'`.

Also, I still don't get why SQL programmers like to shout but it's apparently good practise so... `SELECT` EVERYTHING `FROM` EVERYTHING `WHERE` EVERYTHING `LIKE` EVERYTHING!

### Explanation

LET ME EXPLAIN.

```sql
SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE##S##=DISPLAYNAME--S

                                           --S  -- DECLARE AN INPUT PARAMETER NAMED S
SELECT                                          -- FIND...
       ID                                       -- ID OF THE USERS...
          FROM USERS                            -- IN THE TABLE USERS...
                     WHERE                      -- THAT SATISFIES THE CONDITION...
                          ##S##=DISPLAYNAME     -- S EQUALS THE USERS' DISPLAY NAME
```

Comment: -2 BYTES BY REMOVING THE SPACES AROUND THE EQUALS SIGN

Comment: NINJA'D YOUR NINJA IN CHAT XD

Comment: -1 byte by reversing the order of operands around the equality operator

Comment: -1 byte: `1Id` (the space is unnecessary)

Comment: Wait, is SQL's whitespace requirement the same as Python's? o0

Comment: Apparently so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Don't think it's quite fair to require the input include quotes. +2 bytes to add the quotes back into your answer: `SELECT TOP 1ID FROM USERS WHERE'##S##'=DISPLAYNAME--S`

Comment: It's accepted for Python to do it, so I don't see why ---SQL--- SEDE should be disallowed from using it.

Comment: +1 for the reference to SQL programmers liking to shout (and for a nice choice of language for your answer :)

Comment: why have you put the top 1 in this query? OP said "If there are multiple members with this name, you may choose to output only one ID or all of them"...

Comment: Ohh, I must've missed that. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: i am stupid i searched something about stackexchange api and this was second in the results and i didnt see it

Comment: Seems to fail for every username?

Comment: @SteveFest Still works fine for me. Are you surrounding the input with single quotes?

Comment: No. I just typed SteveFest. I also tried your username and it fails too.

Comment: @SteveFest You *should* be doing it lol. The answer says so.

Comment: Oops, my fault.

Comment: Not sure if the Data Explorer has changed since this was written, but I don't think you need the `--S` at the end any more, it correctly prompts for the parameter with only the `##S##`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), 196 bytes

Thanks @Wondercricket for -6 bytes!

```py
from requests import*
x=lambda s:all([print(a['user_id'])if s==a['display_name']else''for a in get('http://api.stackexchange.com/users?inname=%s&site=codegolf'%utils.quote(s)).json()['items']])and d
```

Uses Stack Exchange API. Fixed the `Leaky N` and `Jorge` errors.

If there are multiple users with the same name, it prints all of them, which is allowed.

Comment: It gives me gzipped data..

Comment: Fails on input `Leaky N`

Comment: @Okx Fixed. ---

Comment: Since you can "report an error **or** return 0" if the user does not exist, can't the last line be just `print a['user_id']`, which will throw a KeyError?

Comment: No, since `Leaky N` would return something.

Comment: @Dopapp Looking at the code, you see that it searches with the parameter `inname`. Thus, SE is only checking that it's *in* the name.

Comment: @Okx, oh yeah I see that now

Comment: You can take advantage of a module within `request` and replace `s.replace(' ','%20')` with `utils.quote(s)` for 173 bytes

Comment: fails for "Jorge"

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), 187 bytes

```python
from requests import*
def f(x):t=get("http://api.stackexchange.com/users?inname="+utils.quote(x)+"&site=codegolf").json()["items"];print[k['user_id']for k in t if k['display_name']==x][0]
```

Returns the user ID if a single user exists, the first user which matches the requirements if more exist, and reports an error otherwise.

Comment: You can remove `/2.2` from the API-url.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks a lot

Comment: **Hint**: Do not try to run it with `fəˈnɛtɪk`, use `\u{...}` instead, because Python does not tolerate non-ASCII

Comment: Python 2, anyways.

Comment: Mentioned this as a comment to Oliver's answer, but you can shed 6 bytes by replacing `s.replace(' ','%20')` with `utils.quote(s)`; `utils` being a module within `requests`

Comment: @Wondercricket Thanks a lot!

Comment: fails for "Jorge"

Comment: Ok, hopefully all the issues are fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>155</s> <s>149</s> <s>142</s> 135 bytes

```js
i=>fetch("//api.stackexchange.com/users?site=codegolf&inname="+i).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>r.items.find(u=>u.display_name==i).user_id)
```

```js
f=i=>fetch("//api.stackexchange.com/users?site=codegolf&inname="+i).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>r.items.find(u=>u.display_name==i).user_id)
```

```html
<input onchange="f(this.value).then(console.log)"><br>Fill input and press Enter
```

Comment: Does it support special characters like in `Jörg Hülsermann`?

Comment: This returned `0` for `Oliver` :(

Comment: Save 7 bytes by replacing `r=>r.items[0]).then(r` with `({items:[r]})`.  [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) ftw!

Comment: You can use: `i=>fetch('//api.stackexchange.com/users?site=codegolf&inname='+i).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>r.items[0].user_id)` as it'll return a promise error if it failed. You can also just do `i=>fetch('/users?site=codegolf&inname='+i).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>r.items[0].user_id)` and say it needs to be run on the api domain

Comment: Version that fixes bug reported by @Oliver and saves 7 bytes: `i=>fetch(\`//api.stackexchange.com/users?site=codegolf&inname=\`+i).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>alert(r.items.find(u=>u.display_name==i).user_id))` - be careful of StackExchange's zero-width spaces when copy-pasting.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by just returning the Promise, rather than `alert`ing the result from it.

Comment: @Downgoat how can I show the result of the promise?

Comment: @Uriel, call the function like so: `f("Shaggy").then(console.log)`. See [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/58974) for more on that consensus. (Note that your solution still fails on usernames containing special characters)

Comment: @Oliver WHAT another oliver???? THERE CAN BE ONLY ONE

Comment: @OliverNi you are Oliver **Ni**, he's Oliver

Comment: @OliverNi Ironically you were the reason `Oliver` used to return `0` :P Apparently "Oliver Ni" is a better match than "Oliver" when searching for "Oliver".

Comment: @Birjolaxew, it's because the default sort order for this query is by reputation descending which, as of this writing, places OliverNi at the top of the list.

Comment: @Shaggy would be `.then(::console.log)`

Comment: No need for the colons in this case, @Downgoat; give it a try in the consensus I linked to above.

Comment: @Shaggy not sure what you mean. Code would error without colons

Comment: @Downgoat: try it [here](http://jsbin.com/derahusowe/edit?console)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org), 173 bytes

```python
lambda s:[i['user_id']for i in get('http://api.stackexchange.com/users?inname=%s&site=codegolf'%utils.quote(s)).json()['items']if i['display_name']==s]
from requests import*
```

### Sample run

```python
>>> f=\
... lambda s:[i['user_id']for i in get('http://api.stackexchange.com/users?inname=%s&site=codegolf'%utils.quote(s)).json()['items']if i['display_name']==s]
>>> from requests import*
>>>
>>> tests = ['musicman523', 'Dennis', 'xnor', 'Leaky Nun', 'Community', 'Any user that does not exist', 'Alex', 'Leaky N', 'Jorge']
>>> for i in tests: print '%-30r -> %s'%(i, f(i))
... 
'musicman523'                  -> [69054]
'Dennis'                       -> [12012, 13891, 14912, 24937]
'xnor'                         -> [20260]
'Leaky Nun'                    -> [48934]
'Community'                    -> [-1]
'Any user that does not exist' -> []
'Alex'                         -> [21536, 69198, 11192]
'Leaky N'                      -> []
'Jorge'                        -> [3716]
```

Fun fact: the result is sorted by reputation, highest first.

Comment: Fails on input `Leaky N`

Comment: Nice trick with `%s`.

Comment: @Okx Not for me, it doesn't. `>>> f('Leaky N')\n48934`

Comment: @totallyhuman It should return `0`. `Leaky N` does not exist

Comment: @Okx Fixed. - -

Comment: `s==t['display_name']and` instead of `t['display_name']==s and` for -1 byte

Comment: Oh, love abusing Python's whitespace requirements. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, so is the import for `requests` not required?

Comment: @Okx Oh, my bad.

Comment: The OP replied: Your 147 byte approach is invalid.

Comment: Aw, maaan... ;-;

Comment: Fails for "Jorge"

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>128</s> 119 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to [Rogem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77406/rogem).

```js
n=>fetch("198.252.206.16/users?site=codegolf&inname="+n).then(r=>r.text()).then(t=>t.match(`\\/([^\\/]*)\\/`+n+`"`)[1])
```

Comment: Think you'd save some bytes with the IPv4 address. (198.252.206.16 instead of api.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 169 bytes

```apl
a←⍞
y←(⎕JSON((⎕SE.SALT.New'HttpCommand').Get'https://api.stackexchange.com/users?site=codegolf&inname=',('\s+'⎕R'\%20')a).Data).items
{a≡1⊃y.display_name:y.user_id ⋄ 0}1
```

This took forever to figure out, lol.

Thanks to @Adám for saving me a lot of time, and a lot of bytes on the HTTP request.

### Explanation

```apl
a←⍞                                 ⍝ Store string input
y←        ('\s+'⎕R'\%20')a          ⍝ Convert spaces to '%20' for query
  (⎕JSON((⎕SE.SALT.New'HttpCommand').Get'https://api.stackexchange.com/users?site=codegolf&inname=',).Data).items
                                    ⍝ Get and parse JSON from API call using ⎕SE (session namespace)
 a≡⊃y.display_name                  ⍝ Is the input equal to the unwrapped user id? 
                                    ⍝ (display name comes as an array of strings)
{                  :y.user_id ⋄ 0}  ⍝ If so, print the user id
                                    ⍝ Else print zero
                                    ⍝ Call function with placeholder arg 1
```

Comment: This can be golfed a lot.

Comment: @Adám `curl` again, I suppose.

Comment: Not sure, as this one returns a compressed result, but you even have spaces around `⋄`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) + HTML, <s>154</s> <s>152</s> <s>151</s> <s>202</s> <s>179</s> <s>161</s> 145 bytes

Sacrificed a few bytes to handle special characters.

Needs to be run under the `api.stackexchange.com` domain. Returns a Promise containing the ID or Throws an error in the Promise if the username can't be found.

```
s=>fetch(`/users?site=codegolf&inname=`+s).then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.items.find(i=>(o.innerHTML=i.display_name,o.innerText==s)).user_id)

<a id=o
```

Note: This solution was developed independently of Uriel's and its comments; if Uriel decides to use the `find` method, I'm happy to roll back to my longer, recursive version.

Comment: I've created [a meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/can-js-answers-require-the-code-to-be-run-at-a-certain-domain) on requiring a certain execution domain, since that *does* save quite a few bytes.

Comment: @Downvoter, please have the decency to leave a comment.

Comment: @Shaggy I would assume for the same reason as that meta discussion was started.

Comment: Downvoter, if you disagree with an established consensus (as @Rogem suggests), please downvote the relevant meta post rather than solutions that adhere to that consensus.